# .Net HTTPClient First request for new client is very slow, Is it possible to increase performance

Tags: .net, performance, request, httpclient

2023-03-30 20:48:52: The duration it took to get headers: 501

2023-03-30 20:48:52: The duration it took to get headers: 78

2023-03-30 20:48:52: The duration it took to get headers: 68

2023-03-30 20:48:52: The duration it took to get headers: 63

2023-03-30 20:48:52: The duration it took to get headers: 63

2023-03-30 20:48:52: The duration it took to get headers: 95

```
                    test.Start();
                headerResponse = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<ResponseHeaderViewModel>($"GenericSync/GetHeaders?tableName={tableName}&ProjectRef={projectRef}");
                test.Stop();
                logger.Log("The duration it took to get headers: " +test.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                test.Reset();
                test.Start();
                headerResponse = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<ResponseHeaderViewModel>($"GenericSync/GetHeaders?tableName={tableName}&ProjectRef={projectRef}");
                test.Stop();
                logger.Log("The duration it took to get headers: " + test.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                test.Reset(); test.Start();
                headerResponse = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<ResponseHeaderViewModel>($"GenericSync/GetHeaders?tableName={tableName}&ProjectRef={projectRef}");
                test.Stop();
                logger.Log("The duration it took to get headers: " + test.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                test.Reset(); test.Start();
                headerResponse = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<ResponseHeaderViewModel>($"GenericSync/GetHeaders?tableName={tableName}&ProjectRef={projectRef}");
                test.Stop();
                logger.Log("The duration it took to get headers: " + test.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                test.Reset(); test.Start();
                headerResponse = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<ResponseHeaderViewModel>($"GenericSync/GetHeaders?tableName={tableName}&ProjectRef={projectRef}");
                test.Stop();
                logger.Log("The duration it took to get headers: " + test.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                test.Reset(); test.Start();
                headerResponse = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<ResponseHeaderViewModel>($"GenericSync/GetHeaders?tableName={tableName}&ProjectRef={projectRef}");
                test.Stop();
                logger.Log("The duration it took to get headers: " + test.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                test.Reset();
```

As you can see from above data, the same request, when executed the first time takes 500ms + Which is not long, but my program is very time sensitive. Is it possible to get first request to be the same as all the rest ? Client is an httpclient generated by IHTTPClientFactory. The api that is being called is working under IIS.

Comment: Are you sure it's the client side which is slow? It might be the server? And can you get a Wireshark trace, it might be something like DNS or Certificate Revocation taking a long time

Comment: @Charlieface I would assume yes, since with Postman it doesn't even get that long first request with postman is 200ms and all the reset 70ms. But I guess that's a good idea to double check which side it is.